# problem with vue draggable width in table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, draggable, bulma

I'm using [`vuedraggable`](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) inside a Bulma table, but it creates a styling problem:

[image: screenshot]

It's not a problem of the Bulma table. I used this in my own table, and the same issue occurs.

**Here is my code:**

```html
<table class="table is-fullwidth is-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>brand</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>brand</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" v-if="featureds.length == 0">0 Models Found</td>
        </tr>
        <draggable v-model="furds" :options="{group:'furds'}" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false" @change="onChnage">

            <tr class="dragndrop" v-for="featured in furds">
                <td class="drag-icon"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></td>
                <td>{{ featured.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ featured.brand.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ featured.created_at | moment("MMMM Do, YYYY") }}</td>
                <td><a :href="`/manage/featured/${featured.id}`">View</a></td>
                <td><a :href="`/manage/featured/${featured.id}/edit`">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        </draggable>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of wrapping tr with draggable,pass tbody as draggable element.

```
<draggable element="tbody" v-model="furds">
```

See the link for better understanding:
https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/L54yu3L9/ (Example with table) (found in vue draggable official doc)

[[**Update: full code(based on question)**]]

```
<table class="table is-fullwidth is-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>brand</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>brand</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <draggable element="tbody" v-model="furds"> <!-- change here -->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" v-if="featureds.length == 0">0 Models Found</td>
        </tr>
            <tr class="dragndrop" v-for="featured in furds">
                <td class="drag-icon"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></td>
                <td>{{ featured.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ featured.brand.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ featured.created_at | moment("MMMM Do, YYYY") }}</td>
                <td><a :href="`/manage/featured/${featured.id}`">View</a></td>
                <td><a :href="`/manage/featured/${featured.id}/edit`">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        </draggable>
</table>
<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";
  export default {
      components: {
      draggable
    },
...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try to explain the code or post the code here because if links die it doesn't help anyone

Comment: Is it OK now? @Isaac

Answer (score 4):

The styling issue occurs because `vuedraggable` uses a `<div>` as its root element by default, and that `<div>` (along with its contents) is stuffed into the first column of the table.

*Solution:* `vuedraggable` allows changing its root element with the [`tag`](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#tag) property, so you could set it to `tbody`, replacing the existing `<tbody>` in the `<table>`:

```html
<table>
  <!-- FROM THIS: -->
  <!--
  <tbody> 
    <draggable> 
      <tr v-for="featured in furds">
        ...
      </tr>
    </draggable>
  </tbody>
  -->

  <!-- TO THIS: -->
  <draggable tag="tbody">
    <tr v-for="featured in furds">
      ...
    </tr>
  </draggable>
<table>
```

[image: Edit Integrating vuedraggable with Bulma table]